# Blender crash while rendering image after building BVH

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

[image: The BVH value goes to 100% and the whole blender program gets closed]

Once render is started, the building BVH value goes to 100% and then the whole Blender program gets closed !
What could be the reason ?

Comment: My first guess would be that you're using the 32bit blender version on a 64bit operating system or vice versa.

Comment: i dont think so ....cuz i hav already made 2 projects succesfully  and renfdered it !!! but when i render this one .....it crashes !!!

Comment: are you rendering on cpu or gpu? have you tried both with the same result? You may also try launching blender from command line to see additional hints displayed in the command line after blender crashes.

Comment: how to do that !! ??

Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=How+to+Run+a+Program+on+Command+Prompt

Comment: Welcome to the Blender.SE! Add some details about what kind of scene are you rendering - are there any [volumetric materials](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/materials/volume.html), how many objects, how many image textures, etc and your PC specifications, especially what amount of memory. [Upload your file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com) for better investigation of your particular problem.

Comment: I am making a teddy bear mr zak !! And as per cocoknight i triesd to open my blender file using CMD it shows python35.dll is missing ..but it is not mission !! plzz help

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem. In my scene I used completely overloaded particle settings. Rducing children from 300 to 100 (before Mem. 3,97 GB, after Mem.1,97) fixed it and redering worked. Good luck