# My Model is not rendering after adding hair !! The uploading BVH value goes to 100 % and the blender program closes

Tags: rendering

There maybe some possible outcomes .. i rendered it succcessfully without adding the particle system : hair !!

Comment: Can you upload your file?

Comment: It appears you already asked this question - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49708/blender-crash-while-rendering-image-after-building-bvh?rq=1. Please don't post it more then once; edit original one with more details / screenshots / blend file.

Comment: If you where able to render your model before adding hair it is possible that you've created a scene that cannot be rendered in your machine. Please edit your original post and add information on your scene. Add an image of your particle/hair settngs and also describe what kind of computer you are using.

Comment: Sir,This is not a duplicate ..in last question i asked about not rendering ..but in this i gav the reason also ..that hair is not rendering,,it is crashing ..https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LCghBIUZyuM
i am following this video ....Anyways in last post my doubt was not cleared !!!!!